# Regular Expression Find Tag within another tag

Tags: html, regex, tags

I want to find all br tags inside of table tag using regular expressions. This is what I have so far:

```
<table[^>]*>(((<br/>)(?!</table>)).)*</table>
```

But this code doesn't work in notepad++.

This is what am testing the regular expression with:

```
<table>
</table>
<table>
<br/>
</table>
```

Basically the last 3 lines should be found with the regular expressions but the one regular expression I listed above doesn't find anything.

Comment: In case anyone doesn't understand j08691's reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Does anyone have an answer to this question other than p.s.w.g's reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
<table(?: [^<>]+)?>(?:(?!</table>).)*<br/>.*?</table>
```

with dot-matches-all modifier `s`.

[Demo.](http://regex101.com/r/rD9mV4/1)

Explanation:

```
<table # start with an opening <table> tag
(?: [^<>]+)?
>
(?: # then, while...
    (?! #...there's no </table> closing tag here...
        </table>
    )
    . #...consume the next character
)*
<br/> # up to the first <br/>
.*? # once we've found a <br/> tag, simply match anything...
</table> #...up to the next closing </table> tag.
```